# Sort 2D Array in Java based by Row

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I have an 2D String[][] array like this:

```
Date     Product1    Product2     Product3
01/01    10          50           100
02/01    10          50           100
03/04    10          50           100
Sum      30          150          300
```

and I want to sort it by the Sum row ascending. The final result should be:

```
Date     Product3    Product2     Product1
01/01    100         50           10
02/01    100         50           10
03/04    100         50           10
Sum      300         150          30
```

I can order it with Arrays.sort per line, but how to do it efficiently by row?

Comment: It would be provavly easier to have class like `ProductInfo` which will wrap data like `sum` `name` `lis of data/value pairs`. This way you could easily sort such array using comparator which will compare value of `sum` field.

Comment: There is static method `Arrays.sort()` which accepts a custom comparator: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator). But for its use, your array should be transposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create new temporary array (or List) of objects which can store value of `sum` and `columnId`. Then order this array using `sum`.
This way new order of `columnId` will show you how your original array should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-D string array is probably not the best representation for this. It's going to be difficult for you to manipulate the data. I would encapsulate the product and date information inside its own object:

```
public class ProductDateInformation { //Use a better name - this is just a placeholder because I'm not sure what it is you're describing
    private String productName;
    private Date date;
    private int amount;

    ...
}
```

Then you can maintain a `List<ProductDateInformation> productList`. From here you can group by `productName` and just sum up `amount`, and then sort by it as well. This uses Java 8's streaming API:

```
Map<String, Integer> sorted = productList
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDateInformation::getProductName),
                Collectors.summingInt(ProductDateInformation::getAmount)
            ).entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Entry::getKey, 
                Entry::getValue,
                (value1, value2) -> value1,
                LinkedHashMap::new
            ));
```

So what's happening here is the following:

- `stream()` just creates a "stream" out a list. This gives you access to the Stream API which gives you a bunch of methods related to transformation, collection, reduction, aggregation, etc.
- `collect(...)` collects the results into some kind of object. Here we're creating a map by grouping on `productName` (so all instances with the same product name will be grouped together) and then we sum based on `amount`. This is essentially calculating the same information you have in the last row of your 2-D array. This information is returned in a map where the key is the product name, and the value is the sum of all the amounts for that particular product name.
- `entrySet().stream()` streams the items in the entry set. The entry set is a set of all the entries in a map. Recall that we collected the information into a map, and now we want to sort it. So we need to look at each entry in the map. So we will access the entry set and create a new stream out of it.
- `sorted()` means that we want to sort the items in the stream in some manner. Here we are passing in a comparator that says that we want to sort by the value of a map entry (i.e., the sum of the amounts).
- `.collect(...)` in this call to `collect`, we are simply collecting the information into a new map. This map will also be keyed by product name, but will be sorted based on the `amount` sum. We are specifically telling it to create a new map using the `LinkedHashMap` variant so that we can preserve order.

Comment: How resulted map will be sorted by sum? By default, toMap() uses hash map as storage.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou whoops you're right. I will have to use another variant of `toMap` and tell it to use `LinkedHashMap`.